# ERROR: Uncaught exception in luigi (TypeError: must be string or buffer, not None)

Tags: subprocess, luigi

I am having trouble while calling /triggering Luigi Task from a python code.

- Basically i need to trigger a luigi task just like we do on command line, but from a python code
- I am using supbrocess.popen to call a luigi task using a shell
  command
- I have a test code named as test.py and have a test class in module
  task_scheduler.py which contains my luigi task (both modules in same location/dir)

```html
        import luigi
        class TestClass(luigi.Task):
            # param = luigi.DictParameter(default=dict())

            def requires(self):
                print "I am TestClass req"

            def run(self):
                with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write("asasasas")

                print "I am TestClass run"
```

```html
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("python -m luigi --module task_scheduler TestClass", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print p.pid
(output, err) = p.communicate()

print "-------------O/P-------------"
print output
print "-------------error-------------"
print err
```

But I am getting the error as

```html
52688
-------------O/P-------------

-------------error-------------
ERROR: Uncaught exception in luigi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/retcodes.py", line 61, in run_with_retcodes
    worker = luigi.interface._run(argv)['worker']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/interface.py", line 238, in _run
    return _schedule_and_run([cp.get_task_obj()], worker_scheduler_factory)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/interface.py", line 172, in _schedule_and_run
    not(lock.acquire_for(env_params.lock_pid_dir, env_params.lock_size, kill_signal))):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/lock.py", line 82, in acquire_for
    my_pid, my_cmd, pid_file = get_info(pid_dir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/lock.py", line 67, in get_info
    pid_file = os.path.join(pid_dir, hashlib.md5(cmd_hash).hexdigest()) + '.pid'
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not None
```

Can anyone please suggest me what I am doing wrong here?
The command "python -m luigi --module task_scheduler TestClass" works perfectly if I use shell prompt

Answer (score 2):

I just tried executing the test.py from command line.
It seems when I was using the IDE to run (PyCharm) then only it gives this issue

Comment: Could you somehow fix that problem for PyCharm? I'm having the same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in version `2.2.0`. Check github issue [#1654](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/1654)